# How accurate is ALGO= All in VASP?

Tags: vasp, convergence-test

I was facing convergence problems in my 2D system, but after I have used the `ALGO = All` tag the convergence problems have gone.
I would like to know how accurate is this option comparing to `ALGO = Normal` and `ALGO = Fast` options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ALGO` only refers to the method used to reach convergence, as a result there is no difference in accuracy.  `ALGO = Normal / Fast` tends to be faster than `ALGO = All`, however this can be system / level of theory dependent.

It should be noted, this isn't strictly true since you can optimize to a different ground state minimum.  This can result in a different magnetic structure in some cases, but I have never seen this problem in practice.